# How to tweak the security policy of Chrome, in order to run "unsafe" snippets in the console?

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy, google-developer-tools

I am used to open Chrome devtools and try code snippets in the console: it's fast and powerful.

However, AFAIS it's not possible to use `eval` or `with`, because such code snippets trigger the browser security policy.

[image: console refusing eval]

I know I can tweak my browser by modifying the `chrome://flags`. However, in this case there doesn't seem to be such a flag.

Am I right? Or is there a way to make the devtools console more lenient?